# HDMI second monitor not displaying

Tags: hdmi

The system detect the monitor but the monitor says "not signal", with Windows 10 works great. I have Elementary OS 0.4.1 loki installed and Intel HD Graphics.

Comment: Same problem here. Not detecting any displays, using a USB-c to VGA cable